# ViewController's view is nil; using subviews only; is this ok?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

doing this in AppDelegate:

`viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Is there any problem with *not* defining a viewController's view (using `setView` or `viewController.view=`) and simply adding `subviews` of the view only? What difference does it make if you put most of your app displayed content in a subview rather than the main root `view` property itself?

is it a problem if `viewController.view` remains `nil` (or whatever state it is in if there is no implementation of `loadView` or a nib) but you actively manipulate subviews of `viewController.view` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** a problem if `viewController.view` is nil, because then it has no view to display or for you to add subviews to. However, if you don't specify a `nibName` when you init viewController and there is no nib with the same name as your UIViewController's subclass, `viewController.view` will end up as a blank view that takes up the whole screen, i.e. not nil.

It is kind of awkward to say that you are displaying content in subviews *rather than* the main view, since practically speaking your subviews are just (sub)parts of the main view. You almost never draw/display content directly in the top level view; 99.9% of the time you'll be using subviews like UILabels, UITextViews, UIImageViews, etc., etc. to do that, which get added as subviews to the top level view.

Comment: You can pass nil to `nibName` if the nib and the view controller subclass share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The `.view` is set to a plain UIView if there is no nib and no implementation of loadView. So it is fine to add subviews to it. If the view property is ever nil, then loadView is called to reload it.

From the [loadView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView):

> The default implementation of this method looks for valid nib information and uses that information to load the associated nib file. If no nib information is specified, the default implementation creates a plain UIView object and makes it the main view.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this myself. You **can** define a `UIViewController` with no nib. So you would do something like `[MyUIViewController new];`. However you have to give it's view at least a background color otherwise it won't show. So:

```
myView = [MyUIViewController new];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```